# Get all characters before first instance of another char

Tags: bash, shell-script

Say I have

```
npmv="3.4.5";
```

what is the simplest way to get all the characters before the first dot? In this case that would be "3"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npmv="3.4.5"
major=${npmv%%.*}

printf 'The major version number is %s\n' "$major"
```

The parameter substitution `${variable%%pattern}` will remove the *longest* suffix string matching `pattern` from the value of `$variable`.  The pattern is treated as a filename globbing pattern, not a regular expression. This is a standard parameter substitution that will work in all POSIX shells.

The same thing but with a single `%` would remove only the final `.5` of the string in the example (the *shortest* matching suffix pattern).  For prefix strings, use `#` instead of `%`.

See also [the section on parameter expansions in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), and your shell's manual.